# Qt QLabel rich text tabulation

Tags: c++, qt, richtext, qlabel

I have QLabel with rich text containing HTML anchor tag. I need to make tabulation in this tag's text, i.e. to get my QLabel displaying something like this: "This is"\t"example", where "\t" is tabulation symbol. I've tried to use QString's '\t' control symbol, tried to use RTF's "\tab"-tag, but nothing helps. Qt docs say that there is no tabulation tag in supported HTML subset. It only works if I use "pre" - tag, but it modifies the font of my text, I don't want that.

Is there another way to achieve my goal?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just use pre for the tabulation. I mean only for tabulation. For example `"text text <pre>(press tab)</pre> text text"`

Comment: But it inserts a line break, i.e. it displays line break before "pre" and after.

Comment: Then you can use `&nbsp;` characters maybe. Is it really necessary to use the tab character?

Comment: Yes, I've tried &nbsp, but it doesn't work too. Yes, unfortunately, it's necessary.

Comment: You can set a stylesheet for QLabel and use `text-indent` tag maybe. But Are you sure `&nbsp;` doesn't work? If you wrote it like in your comment, I mean ending with a comma, it wouldn't work.

Comment: Like so: label->setStyleSheet("QLabel {text-indent: 50px; }");

Comment: You are right, I've made a mistake: used "&nbsp" without ";". Now it works, I use it. Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome. Edit: I didn't want to bring this up, but you could at least upvote my comment. :(

Comment: I didn't want to bring this up, but you could at least upvote my comment. :(

Comment: I wanted to do this, but as far as I remember, it's possible only to upvote an answer, not a comment. Please, form your comment as an answer and I upvote it right now.

Comment: Comments can be upvoted.

Comment: I understand, voting up is only possible with reputation at least 15, I don't have it. But I marked your answer as right, so it increases your reputation. Sorry, I didn't want to hurt you.

Comment: No problem. I've been there not so long ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `&nbsp;` characters maybe.